# Django: "No migrations to apply" for existing server database

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, deployment

Added a small model 'new_model' in existing app 'existing_app' on Django,
Entered commands manage.py makemigrations and manage.py migrate. It migrated perfectly the changes to local database.
Tried to apply same on heroku but its not working there. I then tried to setup heroku database in local settings.py of project and migrations worked, but it shown some well known error. I have attached the output with this discusssion. Attaching the final screenshot [the final screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GqdP.png) as output.

************Just In Case if it may help************_________
The following are the methods I have applied before the final solution:-

1. With heroku run manage.py makemigrations
2. Adding makemigrations command to procfile
3. Pushing migrations as well, so it may replace server migrations
4. Heroku bash and tried "makemigration" and "migrate" on it

[Alternate solution result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0viEQ.png) [Alternate solution result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYyE4.png)

The all four mentioned steps provided this output:- "No migrations to apply, and on migrate it shows you dont have new migrations",
helping out to migrate changes on database.
Thank You.

Comment: Are you able to see your latest migration files on heroku?

Comment: Yes @Gokulnath , previously only heroku migrations were on server, But they were unable to get updated with makemigrations and migrate command. Then tried to have migrations as local on heroku with push and got relation "accounts_newmodel" does not exist.